# Mysql transaction doesn't work

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am trying to find what is the problem with this SQL transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO address VALUES (null, 'Address name', 18);
-- First INSERT statement is CORRECT
INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, 'First_name', 'Last_name', 'username', 'password', '2', 'email@nowhere.com', last_insert_id(), 1);
-- Second INSERT statement is INCORRECT
COMMIT;
```

First SQL query was successfully executed although the second query was failed.
Purpose of transaction is to execute all statements or none.
Both users and address tables are InnoDB.
Did I write this transaction correctly?

Comment: Thats true. But status of 2nd query should be checked by developer and only if it was success the `COMMIT` should be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just solved problem. I put transaction inside procedure and also add SQL code for SQL EXCEPTION. Now works fine.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user()
BEGIN

DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
  BEGIN
    -- ERROR
  ROLLBACK;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO address VALUES (null, 'Address name', 18);
-- First INSERT statement is CORRECT
INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, 'First_name', 'Last_name', 'username', 'password', '2', 'email@nowhere.com', last_insert_id(), 1);
-- Second INSERT statement is INCORRECT
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```